# How do I pass a ref string to my method?

Tags: c#

I have the following sniplet of a stored procedure in SQL Server

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Genpwd] 
    @pass varchar(8) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
```

In my c# code, how do I get the output from the stored proc throught the data context?

```
    var pwd = db.usp_Genpwd(..)
```

Intellisense says to put ref string pass in the paranthesis but when I do the following:

```
    var pwd = db.usp_Genpwd(ref string pass);
```

I get a invalid arguments error

I am not sure what goes in the paranthesis as I am outputting a value from the stored proc.

Comment: It's autogenerated, so what does intellisense tell you? But must likely, `pwn.Value`

Comment: What are you using for generating datacontext?

Comment: I guess `pwn.Value` casted to String will give the result.

Comment: _What is the exact text of the error_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`ref` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) means a reference to a variable or field.

In order to call a function that takes a `ref` parameter, you need to pass a variable or field with the `ref` keyword:

```
string v = null;
var pwd = db.usp_Genpwd(ref v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
ObjectParameter pass = new ObjectParameter("pass", typeof(String));
db.usp_Genpwd(pass);
```

And `pass.Value` will contain the result.

Comment: @SLaks [How to: Execute a Query Using a Stored Procedure with In and Out Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx)

Comment: His question says that the method takes a `ref string`.  Maybe he's using LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: I think that the main problem is that he can't even compile. And for invoking SP from context he should do stuff above.

Comment: @SLaks And first (before your edit) question was - "c# datacontext stored proc"...

Comment: I know, but the error in question is clearly about ref parameters.